# Does web2py translate 'en' to 'en'

Tags: web2py

I have started adding some help to my app. I wanted to include something like:

```
{{=T("Help:123")}}
```

And then in the 'en' translation file have:

```
'Help:123' : 'This is the full help text which could be quite long and so i dont want to put it into each language file. I just want to put in the short code',
```

But alas, my 'en' translation is not working. Should this work? If not, what is the best way to avoid having to repeat long strings in each language file?

Comment: Do you have `T.set_current_languages` in a model file somewhere?

Comment: No 'T.set_current_languages' that i can find. 

Can I assume by your answer that even though my language is 'en' it should still look in the 'en' translation file and convert my placeholder text to the full thing?

My work around was to create an 'en-en' translation file and put my English text in there. Then i just force my language to be 'en-en'. That gets things translating nicely. But that does seem clumsy.